# Trying to end python thread freezes kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, kivy-language, kivymd

When I try to end a thread with the function `.join()` the program just freezes and the when interacted with it does not respond. I can successfully start the thread but can not end it. The function I am trying to call with the thread does operations outside of the kivy gui like recognising speech with the speech recognition module. This may also be the problem. The gui does not freeze when I start the thread so this is very unusual behavior. Here I will show you the function that causes the thread to start, the .kv file and a description of function the thread calls.

## The function that calls thread code

```
def on_checkbox_active(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            self.root.ids.Main_Label.text = "ON"
            self.th = threading.Thread(target=voice_session)
            self.th.start()

        else:
            self.root.ids.Main_Label.text = "OFF"
            self.th.start()
```

## The .kv file

```
MDFloatLayout:

    MDSwitch:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_active: app.on_checkbox_active(*args)

    MDLabel:
        id: Main_Label
        text: "OFF"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .7}
        halign: "center"
```

## The main function that is called by the thread **description**

This function listens to people using the microphone, converts it to text, talks back to the user and carries out process's the user wishes to carry out. I had to put this in a thread because it was pausing the kivy app so I just moved it out of the way onto another thread.


Hope you know the answer and can help me and anybody now or in the future with this problem.

Comment: From the [documentation for join](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join): `This blocks the calling thread`. It does not end the thread.

Comment: `join()` doesn't ends thread but it only waits for its end. You have to stop thread on your own. If other thread runs some `while True` loop then you could use global variable ie. `running = True` with `while running:` and later set `running = False` to stop this loop. And then `join()` waits untill thread clearly ends job. So your real problem is in `voice_session` which you didn't show.